# Importing classes that contain file paths to read

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following file structure:

```
app/
  data/
    data.csv
  module/
    __init__.py
    script.py
  __init__.py
  config.py
```

My config class contains a set of Pandas dataframes read in from csv files. These dataframes are used across my code base:

```
import pandas as pd

class Config:
     data = pd.read_csv('data/data.csv')
     data2 = pd.read_csv('data/data2.csv')
```

My script contains:

```
from config import Config
```

Which returns:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'data/data.csv' does not exist
```

if the run.py script is stored anywhere but the top level.

Is there any way to have class that has some stored file paths without causing a file not found error if importing the class in different scripts across the code base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify the file in path resolved by the current file. For example, if your `app/config.py` is this:

```
import pandas as pd

class Config:
     data = pd.read_csv('data/data.csv')
     data2 = pd.read_csv('data/data2.csv')
```

You want to write the path like this:

```
     mydir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
     data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(mydir, 'data/data.csv'))
     data2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(mydir, 'data/data2.csv'))
```

which `__file__` is the magic variable in Python to tell you which file you're in.

Basically, whenever your script try to open a file, it is relative to your current directory. Therefore, you need the above trick to find the file relative to the script's directory instead of current dir.